# How to show login window and hide main window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

When my application starts it shows a login window before main window displays. That is because I display the login window and wait for results during the InitializeComponent() process.

Now I have created a logout button that hides the main window and shows the login window again. But I am having trouble when it comes to showing the main window again.

I am not sure that this is the right way to go about swapping between login and the main window.

I would like some advice on how to perform this process correctly, I am sure there are various approaches. I am using MVVM so this needs to be accounted for.

Look forward to some ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login, if successful should show the main window; in no way the main window should even be created on a failed logon.

When you login you actually start a new session, it makes more sense to create a new instance of main window each time and will be probably easier to handle on your side.

A simple practical example would be : how are you going to deal with existing changes on the main window, reset them to their default value ? Sounds silly to me. By far it's better to create a new window each time.